# Node.js how to allow user to login with username OR email

Tags: node.js, authentication

I have a login/registration system in Node that works just fine. However, at the moment the user can only login via their email, but I want the user to be able to login with either their email OR their username. I believe the problem exists in my model (my system takes on an MVC approach), but I'll include the pertinent controller code as well.

userController.js

```
module.exports.post_login = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const user = await User.login(email, password);
    const token = createToken(user._id);
    res.cookie('jwt', token, { httpOnly: true, maxAge: maxAge * 1000 });
    res.status(200).json({ user: user._id });
  }
  catch (err) {
    const errors = handleErrors(err);
    res.status(400).json({ errors });
  }

}
```

userModel.js

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  //some user schema code that works just fine 
});

userSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
  next();
});

// static method to login user
userSchema.statics.login = async function(email, password) {
  const user = await this.findOne({ email });
  if (user) {
    const auth = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (auth) {
      return user;
    }
    throw Error('incorrect password');
  }
  throw Error('incorrect email');
};

const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Here, let me include the view file. Sorry about that.

login.ejs

```
        <form action='/register' class="form" method='POST'>
        <div id='login'>
            <h1>Greetings!<h1>
                <h4>We're so happy you've returned.<h4>
                <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="email" autocomplete='off'
                placeholder="Username or Email Address" required />
                </div>
                <div class="email error"></div>
                <div class="input-group">
                <input type="password" name="password"
                placeholder="Password" autocomplete='off'
                required />
                <div class="password error"></div>
                </div>
                <button type='submit' class='btn'><span>Login</span></button><br />
            <p>
            <h6><u><a href="forgot-password.php">Forgot Password?</a></u></h6>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
      const form = document.querySelector('form')
      //const usernameError = document.querySelector('.username.error')
      const emailError = document.querySelector('.email.error')
      const passwordError = document.querySelector('.password.error')

      form.addEventListener('submit', async (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        //reset errors
        /*usernameError.textContent =*/ emailError.textContent = passwordError.textContent = '';
        // get values
        //const username = form.username.value
        const email = form.email.value
        const password = form.password.value

        try {
          const res = await fetch('/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
          })
          const data = await res.json()
          console.log(data)
          if(data.errors){
            //usernameError.textContent = data.errors.username 
            emailError.textContent = data.errors.email
            passwordError.textContent = data.errors.password
          }
          if(data.user){
            location.assign('/profile')
          }
        }
        catch (err) {
          console.log(err)
        }
      })
    </script>
```

I realize that in the controller I need to add the username when requesting the body & in the try statement, but I'm gonna wait to see what you guys/gals suggest.

The problem likely exists in the model at the findOne() method: `const user = await this.findOne({ email });`.

I'm just not sure what method to use instead & I'd rather defer to your suggestions on how to include the array at that spot (I'm assuming I'd need a `username, email` type of array). Any help would be appreciated. If you need more code, please let me know & I'll provide it. Thanks!

Comment: `$or: ` is not working. The problem is that in login.ejs I define "email" as `const email = form.email.value`, but I have nothing in the form to define the username. How would I extract the username from the MongoDB collection instead of from the form?

Answer (score 0):

you need to find the user by his username or email
I think this could help replace

```
const user = await this.findOne({ email });
```

by

```
const user = await this.findOne(
    {
        $or: [
             { email },{ username }
        ]
    }
)
```

username should be read from request body as you say

Comment: Thx, I haven't run the code yet, but I will tomorrow. Just letting you know I've included the view file (login.ejs), which I think may also help. Sorry I forgot it.

Answer (score 0):

If i got that right you have one input which can contain a username or an email. I would suggest to get that value and fetch the user with the or operator.

so you pass only the input value as parameter and fetch the user with.

```
const user = await this.findOne({ $or: [ {email: value}, {username: value} ] });
```

Comment: Thx, I haven't run the code yet, but I will tomorrow. Just letting you know I've included the view file (login.ejs), which I think may also help. Sorry I forgot it.